# Handle popup's in httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is it possible to handle the pop ups using apache http client?

I am trying to access the website. Accessing a particular page pop's up a new window and in http response all i get the pop up new window code in HTML.

Is there a way to redirect to new pop up window from http client?

My code

```
HttpResponse res = null;
HttpEntity entity = null;
DefaultHttpClient defClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://sudhaezine.com/svww_loginform.php?email=guest@xxx.com&password=yyy&brw=safari");
res = defClient.execute(httpost);
entity = res.getEntity();

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
String str;
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(new String(str.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
}
entity.consumeContent();
```

This gives following response

```
<html><head>  <title></title></head><META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh content=30;url=thankyou.php><body background="images/bg1.gif"><script language="javascript">var popupstr='';   //var bor = navigator.appName;   //alert(bor);   doPopUpWindow = window.open("svww_index1.php","StarView",'width=800,height=600,left=0,top=0'+popupstr);  // if (!doPopUpWindow) {       //Popup blocked open with in current browser window.     //  doPopUpWindow = window.open("svww_index1.php","_parent",'width='+ screen.availWidth +',height='+ screen.availHeight +',left=0,top=0'+popupstr);  // }    try{ var obj = doPopUpWindow.name;  // window.close();//WindowOpen.close();//alert("Popup blocker NOT detected");    }   catch(e){       doPopUpWindow = window.open("svww_index1.php","_parent",'width='+ screen.availWidth +',height='+ screen.availHeight +',left=0,top=0'+popupstr); }</script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't automatically handle such pop-ups with http client because they are created via client JavaScript code. So you need client with JS interpreter (like web browser).

You can proceed by reverse-engineering JavaScript code, passing parameters you grab from response body to resulting function and making new request with http client to generated url. This process is called [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).